# Cambiar password de conexión en DTS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

En nuestro servidor SQL Server 2012, corremos unos DTS que realizan la carga de datos desde archivos TXT hacia la base de datos.

Estos procesos corren en el programador de tareas de Windows por medio del llamado al programa DTExec.exe /f archivo_del_dts

Todo esto estaba operando bien, hasta que se cambio el password del usuario sa.

El error dado en el registro de eventos es, cuando corre la tarea de los dts es:

> "Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'sa'. Motivo: la contraseña no
>   es válida para el inicio de sesión proporcionado. [CLIENTE:
>   127.0.0.1]"

Hasta el momento no he dado con el lugar en donde se configura los datos de la conexión, pese a que en el visual studio Shell puedo ver la conexión en el administrador de conexiones y configurar el nuevo password, funcionando correctamente el DTS sobre este entorno.

Mi consulta es ¿De donde puede estar tomando los datos de la conexión al ejecutarse con el DTExe.exe? y ¿Como puedo cambiar los datos de allí?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que debes hacer es editar cada uno de tus paquetes dts de la siguiente manera
das doble clic sobre tu fuente ya sea origen o destino
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego das clic donde dice new, el cual te llevara a tu origen de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego de esto das clic en `new` y creas tu nuevo origen de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

añade tus credenciales nuevas y de esta manera podras seguir trabajando sobre tu dts sin perder tu mapeo entre las tablas

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. He tenido dificultad para encontrar el OLE DB Source editor para realizar el cambio, quizás sea por la versión del SQL Server la cual es 2012.

Comment: mira, perdon por la tardanza. Debes hacer este proceso con sql server data tools, mas no con sql. Ya que sql server data tools es el idoneo para realizar este tipo de procesos mas no desde sql server

Comment: Sql server data tools es una herramienta para trabajar con paquetes dts

Comment: Muchas gracias, encontré la herramienta, probaré realizar los cambios.